# How to use subprocess.Popen with multiple creationflags?

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to execute a node command on the shell, and I need python not to wait until node is closed before moving on to the next line of code, so I use the creation flag: `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`, but I also want the window not to show up on screen, so I'd like to use `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` too. The name seems to indicate more than one can be used, and in fact the docs say:

> creationflags, if given, can be **one or more** of the following flags:
> `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`
>
> `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`
>
> `ABOVE_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS`
>
> `BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS`
>
> `HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS`
>
> `IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS`
>
> `NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS`
>
> `REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS`
>
> `CREATE_NO_WINDOW`
>
> `DETACHED_PROCESS`
>
> `CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE`
>
> `CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB`

But I can't find a way to use more than one at once. If I try with a tuple or a list it gives an error saying: `CreateProcess() argument 6 must be int, not tuple`. I also couldn't find any examples of `Popen` being used with more than one creationflag.

Is there simply no way to call this with both flags? If not, how can I achieve my purpose of detaching the process and also not having an ugly black window show up on the screen?

My code:

```
def inicializar_API_biblia():
    pathApiBibliaLocal = r'C:\\Users\\adassa\Desktop\\Programacao\\api-biblia\\index.js'
    pid = subprocess.Popen(['node', pathApiBibliaLocal],
          creationflags=(subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW, subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)).pid
```

Comment: They're probably bitwise flags, to be combined with the binary or operator `|` e.g. `subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW | subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`

Comment: You mean like this? 

`creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW|subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` I tried it, but apparently neither flag got applied.

Comment: that's what i was thinking. i don't have windows to try it out myself

Comment: That _is_ how it's often done, on Windows. You should be able to verify it by looking up Microsoft's documentation of them.

Comment: Maybe the combination of `CREATE_NO_WINDOW | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` doesn't really make sense. (The fact that one or more flags may be specified doesn't imply that all combinations are meaningful.) Can you edit the question to include more information about your original problem of stopping the "normal script flow"? As it now stands, the question appears to be the textbook case of an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @user4815162342  You were right. I thought they might be incompatible because of the names, but figured it was just the name, since I guessed the idea behind the effects of each flag were very different, but it turns out that the binary or with "DETACHED_PROCESS" did the trick. I edited the question, as ou seggested, to specify more clearly what I meant by "normal script flow". Do you mind writing an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: *I need python not to wait until node is closed before moving on to the next line of code* - But `subprocess.Popen` **doesn't** wait until the subprocess finishes before moving on. You need to call a method like `wait()` or `communicate()` for that. How did you conclude that `subprocess.Popen` does this, do you have a minimal example that shows this behavior?

Comment: @user4815162342 It seems you're right. I'm not sure now. I was previously trying to achieve this using asyncio.create_subprocess_shell, and had a wait on communicate() after, maybe I changed both things at once and didn't realize Popen did it without me having to do anything else. Not sure right now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Ok, I've now posted an answer that attempts to address all of the above points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need python not to wait until node is closed before moving on to the next line of code

Such modifications should not be necessary, as `subprocess.Popen` doesn't wait until the subprocess finishes before moving on.

Regarding the remainder of the question, you need to use the bitwise-or `|` operator to combine the flags, as in `CREATE_NO_WINDOW | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`. Note that it's possible that that particular combination doesn't make sense. (The fact that one or more flags may be specified doesn't imply that all combinations are meaningful.)

Comment: Great, thanks! In this particular case, `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` and `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` apparently  are not compatible, from my testing. But as you stated, I was wrong to think that I need either of them.