# Hide Popen in exe mode

Tags: python, subprocess, pyinstaller, popen

I wrote a python script which runs a `subprocess.Popen("powershell.exe ssh -p ...")` and when I run it there is no extra console. I converted it to exe with this command:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --icon=icon.ico -F --noconsole app.py
```

when I run the **exe** file, it shows an empty console. I tried `"powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden ssh ..."` but it didn't work.

How can I hide the console?

Comment: Read the subprocess module documentation. There are Windows-only flags for this.

Comment: `subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#windows-constants

Comment: Thank you for your response but unfortunately it's not working, it shows terminal again.

Comment: @Glycerine am I using it the correct way?
`si = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()`
`si.dwFlags = subprocess.STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW`

Comment: @AliEnt Probably. I believe you can also provide the flags without a startup info object: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66467245/how-to-use-subprocess-popen-with-multiple-creationflags , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45104218/subprocess-popen-creationflags - many examples here: https://bitcoden.com/answers/running-a-process-in-pythonw-with-popen-without-a-console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Glycerine comments I found the problem. I thought that I have to or my flags with `subprocess.STARTUPINFO()`, but the solution was super simple, the flags should be passed to `creationflags` input.

```py
process = subprocess.Popen(command, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
```